# Getting listview menu (name) to be passed via intent to another class

Tags: android

I got a listview menu items that I can add dynamically using add button than dialog menu pops out.

The question is, how do I get information from the selected menu to another particular menu via intent  so for each listview menu it has different submenu that can be recognized by its parents menu selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an `onItemClickListener`, like this;

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int item, long id){
             String item = parent.getSelectedItem();
     }
 });
```